# referenceing object, without passing into new object

Tags: ruby

How can I reference an object from a method without passing it as a variable?

I am getting error:

`NameError: undefined local variable or method ‘my_object’ for Myclass:Class`

```
class B 
  attr_accessor :somethings

  include Enumerable  

  def initialize(*values)
    self.somethings = []
  end
end

my_object = B.new({d:'d'})

class Myclass

  def self.my_method
     p my_object
  end
end


Run: Myclass.my_method
```

What I do NOT want to do for all my methods is...

```
  def self.my_method(my_object)
     p my_object
  end
```

I could also solve the issue with use from a global variable

```
$my_object = B.new({d:'d'})
```

However, I only really want to make the variable available to my methods in Myclass class.

Comment: Can it express yourself better?

Comment: The example you gave works as expected (when omitting the undefined function `add_my_values`). Please give an example which produces the NameError you describe.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I tried to rewrite the post, I hope this is more clear.

Comment: @user2012677 Without defining it as a global you wont be able to do what you're looking for. There is no downside passing in the object into a method though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I only really want to make the variable available to my methods in Myclass class.

Then you should define it as an instance variable in corresponding scope of `Myclass`. As it is now, `my_object` is a local variable and is not visible because of the scope gate.

```
class Myclass
  @my_object = B.new({d:'d'})

  def self.my_method
     p @my_object
  end
end
```

Comment: That's what i was looking for, sorry for such a rudimentary question.